# Criar uma imagem com efeito de blur no Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Como posso criar uma imagem com efeito de blur no Xamarin.Android?

Apenas achei soluções em Java e nada realmente funcional e ágil para Xamarin.Android.

O que tentei usar sem sucesso foi o apresentado nessa pergunta: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk)

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Apenas converti o código Java para Xamarin.Android. É ágil e perfeitamente funcional.

Testei outros métodos, os quais se diziam mais ágeis em Java e, pelo menos para mim, foram mais lentos que esse apresentado abaixo.

```
private const float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
private const float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

/// <summary>
/// Cria uma imagem com efeito de blur
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">Contexto</param>
/// <param name="image">Objeto 'Bitmap' com a imagem</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private Android.Graphics.Bitmap CreateBlurredImage(Context context, Android.Graphics.Bitmap image)
{
      int width = (int)Math.Round(image.Width * BITMAP_SCALE);
      int height = (int)Math.Round(image.Height * BITMAP_SCALE);

      Android.Graphics.Bitmap inputBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
      Android.Graphics.Bitmap outputBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(inputBitmap);

      RenderScript rs = RenderScript.Create(context);
      ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.Create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
      Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
      Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
      theIntrinsic.SetRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
      theIntrinsic.SetInput(tmpIn);
      theIntrinsic.ForEach(tmpOut);
      tmpOut.CopyTo(outputBitmap);

      return outputBitmap;
}
```

Caso queira mudar a forma que o blur se comporta, apenas altere a constante BLUR_RADIUS.